# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change the location once it is set

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I am trying to start my application(Eclipse based) it is giving me following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change the location once it is set.
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:137)
    at com.fiorano.studio.fmq.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

It is asking me for workspace. When I select one and do 'ok'. It simply closes and throws above exception. I googled it but not much documentation. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: You would probably have better luck posting this on the eclipse forums.

Comment: @Dgrin91 thanks but found it!

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit and found that you need to add **@noDefault** inside runtime configuration. But it was already in my .ini file. Problem was as follows -

My config file was as follows

```
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-showsplash
-showlocation
-data
–vm
/home/aniket/jdk1.7.0_11/bin
@noDefault
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
```

I changed it to

```
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-showsplash
-showlocation
-data
@noDefault
–vm
/home/aniket/jdk1.7.0_11/bin
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
```

and it worked.I thing @noDefaultmust be put after `-showsplash -showlocation -data` and before specifying

```
–vm
/home/aniket/jdk1.7.0_11/bin
```

I know it sounds a bit silly and I am not sure of exact reason but hope this helps if anyone faces this scenario again.

Comment: `@noDefault` is the value for the `-data` parameter so it must be on the next line to `-data`